# How to use pagination in ASP.NET MVC 4/5 on product lists for each category

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to display my product list of each category with pagination when the user clicks on the category link then link will be like this:

```
/Warehouse/Browse?category=Film

//Warehouse controller used to display the product list
```

My Browse Action in `WarehouseController` will be

```
public ActionResult Browse(string category)
{

    var cat = db.Categories.Include("Products").Single(c => c.CategoryName == category);
    return View(cat);
}
```

Category Model Class:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Product Model Class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

How to use pagination in Browse View?

Comment: @user3956566 I didn't get your point? I am trying to implement PageList here. I know the implementation of PageList in other condition. Above Browse Action only display the products not pagination so how to implement the pagination on the above action method...

Comment: @userKG check out http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application Here you can find one way to do it

Comment: @userKG You need to show your View code since that is where your problem lies. Also you can try using this https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList

Comment: @lbrahim First I am trying to implement the pagination on the controller not the view code...

Comment: @userKG Are you trying to return the whole HTML for pagination from your controller?